# Setting maximumSelectionLength in select2 dropdown dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, jquery-select2

This is my HTML is have two select one is for multiple selection of items in dropdown and the other is for tags.

If the number of selected items are 3 then users should only be able to add 3 tags, not more than 3 and not less than 3

```js
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 8,
});
var selectedValues = $('#paper').val();
var len = selectedValues.length;
$(".js-tags").select2({
    tags: true,
    maximumSelectionSize: len,
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" multiple="multiple" name="paper" id="paper">
    <option value="OP">OP</option>
    <option value="needs">Needs</option>
    <option value="some">some</option>
    <option value="help">help</option>
    <option value="with">with</option>
    <option value="Jquery">Jquery</option>
</select>

<select class="js-tags form-control" multiple="multiple" name="paper_used" id="paper_used">
    <option value="__None"></option>
</select>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 8,
});
var selectedValues = $('#paper').val();
var len = selectedValues.length;
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").on("change", function (e) { 
 selectedValues = $('#paper').val();
 len = selectedValues.length;
 console.log(len);
 $(".js-tags").select2({
  tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
    maximumSelectionLength: len
});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" multiple="multiple" name="paper" id="paper">
    <option value="OP">OP</option>
    <option value="needs">Needs</option>
    <option value="some">some</option>
    <option value="help">help</option>
    <option value="with">with</option>
    <option value="Jquery">Jquery</option>
</select>

<select class="js-tags form-control" multiple="multiple" name="paper_used" id="paper_used">
    <option value="__None"></option>
</select>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Add change event for the first select2. Inside that change event find its selection length and create second select2 dynamically. Hope this will help you.